# Discord bot not giving verify role after verification

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I am making a security discord.py bot that will DM a new member to verify themselves. I am having one issue with this. After the member verifies themselves, the bot has trouble actually giving the member the role. I am storing this information in a JSON file. My JSON file currently looks like this..

[image] This file is called `verifychannel.json`

This stores the channel where it says a new member has joined and to check their dm's to verify. This also stores the verify role. The verify role is the role ID that the bot is supposed to give after they verify. This is where I'm having my issue, the bot cannot give the role after they verify.

My current code is..

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
        with open('verifychannel.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            get_vchannel = json.load(fp)

        try:
            if get_vchannel:
                channel = member.guild.get_channel(get_vchannel[str(member.guild.id)]["Channel ID"])
                roleid = member.guild.get_role(get_vchannel[str(member.guild.id)]["Verify Role"])
                role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=roleid) #I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
        except:
            return
        try:
            message = await member.send(f"Thanks for joining **{member.guild.name}**! The server has requested verification for new members. **Please react to this message with ✅ to verify!** You have one hour to verify!")
            await message.add_reaction("✅")
            await channel.send(f"Welcome {member.mention}! Please check your dm's as I have sent you a message to verify yourself!")
            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'
            try:
                reaction, user = await self.client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=3600, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await member.send("You didn't verify in time! You have been kicked from the server.")
                await member.kick(reason="Didn't verify in 1 hour, possible bot/alt account | Guard")
            else:
                await member.send(f'You have been verified! Enjoy your stay in **{member.guild.name}**!')
                await member.give_roles(role=role)
        except:
            await channel.send(f"{member.mention} You could not be verified because your dm's are not open. Please allow server members to DM you then rejoin the server.")
```

Once a member joins, this is the DM you get..
[image]

Once you react, it says you have been verified. After that, it sends `You could not be verified because your dm's are not open. Please allow server members to DM you then rejoin the server.` So I know the bot could not do `await member.give_roles(role=role)` Meaning that the lines where I define the role and role id are not right. I do not get any errors at all during this process. How can I define the role/role id correctly in order to give the member the verified role?

Comment: `except:` will supress every error, I would recommend either to change it to `except Forbidden:` (need to import `from discord.errors import Forbidden`) or leave out the whole try/except block and running it again. Then you can see what kind of error you're getting

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.
`await member.give_roles(role=role)` needed to be `await member.add_roles(role)`